Is there away to keep photos separated by "generations" on my iphone?
Over the time, a lots of photos accumulate in my iPhone.
After a certain time, I want to start a new "series" or "generation" of photos and by default see only the photos in the new series, not the onld ones. I only want to look at the old photos (in a previous series) occasionally, by explicitly telling the app that I want to see that series.
Until recently, I have dealt with this in the following way:
Whenever I decided that a series is complete, I connected my iPhone to my Mac and copied all pictures to my hard disk, into a directory for this series (say: series1). Then I deleted all pictures from my iPhone, and a new series started. Over the years, this brought me directories on my Mac (series1, series2, ....) and I always have the current series on my iPhone.
While this process was convenient and allowed me to backup the pictures, I now would prefer a similar system, which also keeps all the series on my iPhone.
My first idea was to create an album for this purpose, and discussed this here. I could make an album and put the pictures there, but as I learned from a comment by @hillside on this thread, the pictures are still present in my main library, and if I would delete them there, they would also be gone from my album. Hence after starting a new series, I still see all the old pictures as well.
I would like to have a solution, where I by default see only the current series and only when I switch to a new folder (album?), I see the pictures belonging to that series.
I'm not sure whether this can be done on the iPhone, but if I would organize pictures on my Mac, I would create a folder current and let all pictures go into this folder. When the series is complete, I would rename the folder, and create a new current folder to receive the pictures of the next series.
Can something like this be achieved in the iPhone, maybe with the help of some other app?

If the pictures are in albums then selecting the album will only show those pictures and not the old ones - so I am not clear on what you mean by seeing the old pictures

@mmmmmm: If I take a new picture, and later open the app to look at my pictures, I see all the old ones plus the new one. How could I describe this, so that it is better understandable?

The second grouping on the start screen is recent days ie photos split by days

@mmmmmm : I know, but I don't want to split by days.
